# use android.location.Location.distanceTo(startLocation) to get the distance that sometimes increase and sometimes reduce?

Tags: android, gps, location

In my android Running App, I use android.location.Location.distanceTo(startLocation) to get the distance between startLocation where i start running and endLocation where i stop running. But the distance sometimes increase, sometimes it reduce when i run. anyone help me to solve the question?

my code like this :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(
                    Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
Location startLocation = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(provider);
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double distance = location.distanceTo(startLocation)/1000;
    } 

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
            Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 3,
                        locationListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your track. You always measure the distance between the starting point and your current position. If you run in a straight line, it's fine - the distance always increases:
[image: Straight line]
But if your track is curved, you get an error. look at the picture below:
You run along the solid line from the start point to the end point, ut right after the curve, the distance decreases. The total distance will be the dotted line.
[image: Curved track]
The extreme case is beginning and ending at the same point, because yo'ull get a zero distance!
You must always measure the distance between the current location and the **previous** location, and sum up all the distances.